# JOIN data from bridging table

Tags: mysql

I'm taking a database class and I'm having troubles with using the JOIN command to get the data I need. I hope I'm on the right track...I would appreciate any inputs if there is a better way both in my model and query.

> Sales transaction that each employee has processed

[image: Database ER model], I'm trying to answer the following question:

Here is a query I tried but fail to come up with correct output. I had to use a table alias for sales because I kept getting unique errors. I only have 10 rows in my bridging table however, I got 100 results back...JOIN statements are kicking my butt right now.

```
SELECT sales.cashier, inventory.prod_name, inventory.unit_price 
FROM inventory, sales 
JOIN inv_sales ON inventory_prod_id = inventory.prod_id
JOIN sales AS sales1 ON sales_sales_id = sales_id;
```

edit: Additional requested data

Here is a screenshot of some sample data.

[image: All tables]

I had to put them all on one pic due to site restrictions.

Tables:

- Top, Inv_sales
- Middle, Sales
- Bottom, Inventory

Expected output:

cashier > product name > unit price

Comment: Please add sample input data, expected result and current result in your question

Comment: You are mixing two styles of join, the old way (from with comma separated tables) and the current, more common method (joins with on clauses)  You are missing the relationship for the sales table in the from. Also, you should be using an order by ("_each employee_").

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: @Strawberry, Thanks for the tip, I wasn't sure what the best way to post here was. I will take that into consideration in future questions for sure. Hopefully, I will have learned a little more by then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might try something like this:

```
SELECT s.cashier, i2.prod_name, i2.unit_price 
FROM sales s
JOIN inv_sales i1
ON i1.sales_sales_id = s.sales_id
JOIN inventory i2
ON i1.inventory_prod_id = i2.prod_id
ORDER BY s.cashier,s.date;
```

It uses a unique alias for each table, and uses the modern form of joining tables. Also, since the requirement was to get the sales for each employee, I added an order by so an employees sales would be grouped together.

Comment: Forgive me still a newb here, I tried, entering this verbatim and I get an error. I also forgot to mention I'm using Mariadb not actual MySQL.                                                                                               
    ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '.prod_name, i2.unit_price FROM sales s JOIN inv_sales i1 ON i1.sales_sales_id = ' at line 1

Comment: It appears I made a typo when entering the query. This is exactly what I wanted. Thank you so much for taking the time to assist.

Comment: Glad I could help.